# How do I determine where element.style is being enforced when debugging in Chrome?

Tags: css, html

Ok so I am analyzing my websites applied styles in Chrome and I noticed that one of my div's is automatically enforcing a position:relative which doesn't exist in the div's css at all. So my question is when analyzing in Chrome when I see

```
element.style {

}
```

where is that usually referencing?

The div looks like this in chrome. So I have a css class called left applied to it and then when the webpage loads it has this style="" which is not in the original code.

```
<div class="left" style="height: auto; overflow: visible; width: 785px; padding-right: 5px; position: absolute; top: 0px; ">
```

Comment: `element.style` in Chrome references inline style. Sometimes you can click on a small arrow after the style to see how the inheritance rules were applied.

Comment: The extra inline style is probably coming from JavaScript

Comment: ok thanks guys I am going to start looking there. And I need to learn about inline styles

Comment: Learn about them, but avoid using them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I found out was that the parent elements were enforcing said css on my inner elements. In order for me to get around that hierarchical issue I added the following to each css rule I wanted to override.

```
color:red !important;
```

As an example.